# Cordova/Phonegap Google Play Turn-Based Multiplayer Support

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, game-center, google-play-games

I built an app for iOS and Android in Cordova. I used the following Cordova plugin to support some of the Game Center and Google Play Games features:

https://github.com/cranberrygame/cordova-plugin-game

However, this plugin doesn't support [Turn-Based Multiplayer](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/turnbasedMultiplayer) and I can't seem to find any Phonegap/Cordova plugin that does. My main goal is that people would be able to issue a challenge to their friend, even if they haven't downloaded the app. I suppose I could use their social game ID and build something internally, but it seemed better to leverage what Google and Apple already offer.

Does anyone know of a plugin or any other way to implement this?

Comment: Have you looked at the REST API? https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/gettingstarted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out Cocoon by Ludei? Their plugins support turn-based multiplayer games and are freely available on github. http://cocoon.io
https://github.com/ludei

Comment: Thanks Coda, it looks like this plugin should do what I need: http://ludei.github.io/atomic-plugins-docs/dist/doc/js/Cocoon.Multiplayer.html